# Does summoner heal reduce healing from other heals?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you use summoner heal, I know you get a status effect that reduces subsequent summoner heal effects, but by how much? and does it reduce healing effects from champion abilities/lifesteal/etc?

Answer (score 7):

Heal applies a 35 second debuff that reduces all subsequent Summoner Heal spells, aside from your own, by 50%. This debuff does not affect Lifesteal, Spell Vamp, Health Regen or Champion Heal spells but only other allies' Summoner Heals.

Answer (score 2):

No. The debuff from Heal only applies to the healing from the Summoner Spell Heal.

Back in Beta, it wasn't uncommon to see all 10 summoners running Heal, which horribly affected team fights. The debuff was added to discourage Heal stacking.